# undefined method `events' for nil:NilClass

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I was working with nested attributes, everything seemed to be fine until when I submitted my information and I got this error. It says it is in my EventsController file:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @event = Event.new
        @event.songs.build
    end

    def index
        @songs = Song.all
    end

    def show
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
      @songs = @event.songs.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def create
        @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
        if @event.save
            flash[:success] = "Event Created!"
            redirect_to user_path(@event.user)
        else
            render 'welcome#index'
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private 

      def event_params
        params.require(:event).permit(:name, :partycode, song_attributes: [:event_id, :artist, :title, :genre, :partycode])
      end
end
```

Here is my new.html.erb file in my songs view(handles song submission based on selected event)

```
<br>
<br>
<div class ="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
  <%= form_for Event.new do |f| %>
    <h3>Enter a song:</h3>
    <%= f.fields_for :songs, Song.new do |song_form| %>

      <%= song_form.collection_select(:event_id, Event.all, :id, :name) %>
      <%= song_form.text_field :artist, placeholder: "Artist" %>
      <%= song_form.text_field :title,  placeholder: "Title" %>
      <%= song_form.text_field :genre,  placeholder: "Genre" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Song", f, :songs %>
    <%= f.text_field :partycode %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The link_to_add_fields method is defined in my ApplicationHelper.rb file:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render("songs_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

current_user is defined in Session_helper.rb file:

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def createEvent(event)
    session[:event_id] = event.id
  end



  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end
  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

end
```

Finally, here is my songs_fields file that generates fields only when a user clicks a link that says 'Add songs'

```
<fieldset>  
  <%= f.text_field :artist, placeholder: "Artist" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title,  placeholder: "Title" %>
  <%= f.text_field :genre,  placeholder: "Genre" %>
</fieldset>
```

I feel as though this is the last portion before I get everything in my app to work! So help on this would be tremendous :D

Comment: The error is self-explanatory `@event = current_user.events.build(event_params)` -- `current_user` is `nil` here.

Comment: I understand that error, how would I fix it, is it because I am not signed in to my user when I am adding the song??

Comment: I don't know without further details. There are many ways. Check your configuration. Are you using devise, because `current_user` pertains to it? Are browser cookies being passed properly?

Comment: I will update my question to show how current_user is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question... if you're not logged in, *current_user* will be nil so you will get this error.

Option 1 (ugly): change your logic so *current_user.events* doesn't get called if *current_user* is nil, and just go straight to the render

Option 2 (better): use a *before_action* statement to force *current_user* to be set before the action is run. Depends on what you're using to authenticate, but with Devise it would look like this:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
```

I think maybe:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :log_in(user)
```

might do it for you.